# Using Ionic's Fingerprint AIO for database authentication

Tags: authentication, ionic-framework, fingerprint

I'm building an Ionic app which uses the Fingerprint AIO native plugin.

When using the plugin, and successfully authenticating using my fingerprint, the plugin returns a generated string, which is different each time authentication is successful.

My question is this: Is there a way to use this string to authenticate with a database?

Or more broadly speaking, what are the concepts or best practices when authenticating using a fingerprint?

My first though was to store that generated string and perform a check against my database, however this seems invalid because the string is different each time.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Same question.
Have you found any solutions yet ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't known Fingerprint AIO.

On iOS or Android, when you ask a user to identify with biometric, you only obtain success or failed.

When success, it prove that current fingerprint is fingerprint of smartphone owner. So in your app when fingerprint match is succeed when user could access secured data or functionality.

On android you could save key in keystore and protect it by fingerprint: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/10/new-in-android-samples-authenticating.html